# Windows defender isn't working

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, windows-defender

My Windows defender was turned off because of preinstalled antivirus.

Then the antivirus expired and I want to turn it back on but I can't.

Getting a message: "Your PC isn't monitoring because the app's service stopped. You should restart it now." 

I have tried starting the service by opening services.msc

Comment: have you tried changing the values? Is defender now working again?

Answer (score 1):

Un-install the expired Antivirus software and Windows Defender should kick back into action automatically. You may need to restart the PC after the un-install.

Comment: I did that before

Comment: @GopalChandak Hmm, seems like the expired AntiVirus didn't uninstall completely/properly. What's the name of the expired AntiVirus?

Comment: K7 and I also did run K7 removal tool But it give message "No traces of K7 Antivirus found"

Answer (score 1):

Run [RegOwnershipEx](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.57), take ownership of the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender`, open this key and set the values of the DWORDs `DisableAntiSpyware` and `DisableAntiVirus` to `0`. Now Windows Defender should work again.

Answer (score 0):

I would do what magicandre recommended and then install a new antivirus. I'd bet once you do this and run all of your scans and clean up whatever crap is left behind...Windows Defender may start to work again. A lot of virus/spyware/malware does nasty things like disabling Windows Defender, Windows Update. Probably also a good idea to open Windows update and install the latest "Malicious Software Removal Tool" if you haven't already.

The "best" anti-virus programs change from year to year but looks like currently they include Avira, BitDefender, Kaspersky, etc. Plenty of good paid and free options. Do some research, good unbiased info here:

http://www.tomsguide.com/t/antivirus/

https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/

Once you install one of these run a full scan. Personally I also like to run Malware Bytes after a virus scan to get anything it missed...but don't let it run in the background if you are using something else.